# SQL procedure can't use the function if(exper1,exper2,exper3)

Tags: mysql, sql

The version of Mysql is 5.6.25.
When the code runs,it shows:
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$
DELIMITER' at line 4

```
  DELIMITER $$
  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `TEST` $$
  CREATE PROCEDURE `TEST`(IN aaa INT)
  BEGIN
    SET @abc=if(1>2,3,2);
  END $$
  DELIMITER ;
```

But if I separate the two circumstances above;
they will run well.

```
SET @abc=if(1>2,3,2);
```

If we change the key word "set" into "select",they will run well,too.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `TEST` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `TEST`(IN aaa INT)
BEGIN
--     SELECT @abc=if(1>2,3,2);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I don't know why and who can tell me?
Thanks!

Comment: How are you running these? Bear in mind that DELIMITER isn't a MySQL command as such; it's recognised by the client you're using, not the server. What happens if you remove that last `DELIMITER ;` you've got at the end of your first example?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem from the MySQL Command-Line.

```sql
mysql> USE `test`;
Database changed

mysql> DELIMITER $$

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `TEST`$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `TEST`(IN aaa INT)
    -> BEGIN
    -> SET @abc = IF(1 > 2, 3, 2);
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `TEST`(NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @abc;
+------+
| @abc |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Indeed. Do you maybe have some odd hidden character in the code you're running, @windy? I'm thinking that something odd like a non-breaking space in between the `$$` and the `DELIMITER` might cause these symptoms. Did you copy and paste the code from somewhere, or type it in yourself?

Comment: Thank you very much!  I played the code on the  software called Navicat for MySQL yesterday!Then I turn to play on the cmd and they  run well today!